# How to Set id as a Session value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my JavaScript code,

```
     function register_popup(id,name,msg)
        {                
          for(var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++)
           {   
             //already registered. Bring it to front.
             if(id == popups[iii])
               {
                 Array.remove(popups, iii);                   
                 popups.unshift(id);
                 calculate_popups();
                 return;
                }
           }               
            var element = '<div class="msg_box" style="right:290px" id="'+ id +'">';
                element = element + '<div class="msg_head">'+ id +'';
                element = element + '<div class="close"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\''+ id +'\');">&#10005;</a></div></div>';
                element = element +'<div class="msg_wrap"><div class="msg_body" class="msg-wgt-body"><ul id="chatlog"></ul>'+ msg+'<div class="msg_push" id="textmesage">dg</div></div><div class="msg_footer" ><textarea id="myTextArea" class="msg_input" rows="4" onkeypress="PushMessage(event , this);"+"\n">  </textarea></div></div>';
                element = element + '<div><a href="get_message('+id+'","'+msg+');"></a></div>';
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML + element;  
            popups.unshift(id);      
            calculate_popups();

        }
```

I want to set `id` as a session value in this code. I am new in javascript kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: your question is not that much clear .

Comment: id given inside the function peremeter i want to use that id in other page thats why i want to set id as a session so that i can use this in other page

Comment: do you want php session or javascript local storage session ?

Comment: i want to use this session id inside php code.

Comment: so you need ajax call to set php session .on server side

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var someVal = <?php echo $_SESSION['some_var']; ?>;
</script>
```

That should do it.

Comment: var someVal = <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>; i try this but it does not give me possitive responce

Comment: Are your sure your session variable is set? Do you have session_start(); at the top of the file your other code is in?